# matplotlib.animation huge image

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have a code to animate x and y points chaging in time:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(25,25))
ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
df3=df2.head(20)
def animate(i):
            xs=[]
            ys=[]
            xs=df3.loc[(i-1):i,'logintude'].values
            ys=df3.loc[(i-1):i,'latitude'].values
            ax1.clear()
            ax1.scatter(xs,ys)
ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,frames=range(1000),interval=1000,blit=False,repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

After run the errors is:
 Image size of 460100x333779 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.
I have no idea where from is this size, when using just 20 points from quite large df2 dataset.

Editor does not allowed me to past everything so pasting only core with arrows if it's enought

```
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    240     if 'png' in formats:
--> 241         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    124     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 125     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
   2262                 bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore,
-> 2263                 **kwargs)
    516     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 517         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
--> 429         self.renderer = self.get_renderer(cleared=True)
    430         # acquire a lock on the shared font cache
    453         if need_new_renderer:
--> 454             self.renderer = RendererAgg(w, h, self.figure.dpi)
    455             self._lastKey = key
--> 101         self._renderer = _RendererAgg(int(width), int(height), dpi)
    102         self._filter_renderers = []
```

Comment: Did you try using a smaller figsize, something like `figsize=(10,10)`?

Comment: Could you please post the full error trace?

Comment: No, figsize=10,10 does not change anything. Full error:

Comment: When using `figsize=(10,10)` does it still report the same `460100x333779` pixels? What does `print(fig.dpi)` result in? Do you get the same error when not using an animation?

Comment: It print(fig.dpi) strongly helped, but code does not generate enimation-but it is different problem